# Yii2: как получить внутренний путь (controller/action)?

Tags: yii2

Есть ли способ сразу получить внутренний путь в виде **строки** типа `controller/action`.

**Знаю, что можно сделать так:**

```
$internalRoute = 

  Yii::$app->controller->id . '/' . Yii::$app->controller->action->id
```

**Или так, если в `view`:**

```
$internalRoute = 

  $this->context->id . '/' . $this->context->action->id
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что можно и сразу получить строку `controller/action`?

Comment: Не проще тебе написать статичную функцию, которая будет выводить?)

Comment: Интернет нам подксказывает что можно и так `Yii::app()->urlManager->parseUrl(Yii::app()->request)`

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade, не совсем понял о чём вы. В общем, так как мне нужен был внутренний путь в шаблоне, то я просто пока (так как учусь ещё :)) определил (`define()`) константу.

Comment: @koks_rs, как я понял, так можно было делать в Yii, а в Yii2 такое работать не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить внутренний маршрут в виде строки (`controller/action`) в «любом» месте приложения, нужно обратиться к свойству [route](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#$route-detail) класса [`yii\base\Controller`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html):

```
Yii::$app->controller->route
```

В самом контроллере можно обращаться так:

```
$this->route
```

А в представлении так:

```
$this->context->route
```

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать:

```
yii\helpers\Url;
```

то можно обращаться так:

```
Url::toRoute([]);
```

или

```
Url::to([]);
```

а если нужно получиться адрес страницы, который преобразуется для пользователя, то так:

```
Url::to();
```

Comment: У вас ошибка: если просто передать пустой массив (`[]`), как для `toRoute()`, так и для `to()`, то выскочит `Undefined offset: 0`. А вот если передать массив с одним элементом, для обоих методов, — пустой строкой (`['']`) или просто пустую строку, то вернётся абсолютный (от корня сайта) URL, хотя в документации сказано, что должен `route` (?) ... Метод `to()` при вызове без аргументов также возвращает URL. Всё вышесказанное можно легко проверить, если определить правила для `urlManager`'а. Мне нужен именно внутренний маршрут: `controller/action` (его можно получить как описано в моём ответе).

Comment: У меня в рабочем проекте при `Url::toRoute([]);` и `Url::to([]);`  ошибок никаких нет, но вообще да, метод выдаёт немного не то что нужно :)

Comment: Странно конечно, что у вас не вываливается `Undefined offset: 0`, так как если глянуть в [исходный код](https://goo.gl/UJMqKX), то можно увидеть, что сначала (представляем, что мы передали пустой массив) переданный (первый) аргумент преобразовывается в массив: `$route = (array) $route;` — получаем всё тот же пустой массив. Затем мы обрабатываем элемент с нулевым индексом: `$route[0] = static::normalizeRoute($route[0]);` ... Упс — а нет-то элемента с нулевым индексом. Упрощённый пример: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6dd24dd40296dd9e5c4b6760948008932239136.